# Understanding operator overloading 'const' syntax for use in STL map

Tags: c++, oop, overloading, operator-keyword

I am trying to understand the syntax of operator overloading for `operator <` where the second `const` word needed for the compiler to be happy.

```
bool operator < (const point& rhs) const {  // what's the rationale for the second const word here?
```

Take for example this `struct`

```
struct point {
    int x;
    int y;

    point () : x(0), y(0) {}
    point (int _x, int _y) : x(_x), y(_y) {}

    point operator + (const point& rhs) {
        return point(this->x + rhs.x, this->y + rhs.y);
    }
    bool operator < (const point& rhs) const {
        return this->x < rhs.x;
    }
};
```

This will allow me to use it as key to mymap.

```
map<point,int> mymap;
```

Comment: The first `const` applies to the parameter - the right-hand side of the comparison. The second `const` applies to `*this` - the object the method is called on, which happens to be the left-hand side of the comparison. It's needed for the same reason the first one is needed - to be able to compare two `const point` objects.

Comment: The `+` operator should have the second `const`, too. It should not - and it does not - modify its left operand (`*this`). By the way, none of the `this->` subexpressions is needed in the code shown.

Comment: @CiaPan, agreed, the `this->` is not needed. The second `const` for the `+` operator is not necessary for the compiler to be happy, which is where my confusion comes from. Now that I tried it again, if I dont use `point` in the STL `map`, the second `const` isnt a deal breaker. So, okay, perhaps to use in STL `map` it has to be unambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outer `const` on the end of a method declaration tells the compiler that the method's `*this` object is to be `const`.

`std::map` stores its keys as `const` values. So any operators that are applied to the keys need to be marked as `const`, or else they will fail to compile. `std::map` uses `operator<` by default to order its keys and compare them for equality.

Besides, as good practice, any member method/operator that does not modify the contents of `*this` should be marked as `const` anyway. Doing so lets the user know that such operations are meant to be read-only, and lets the compile use them in expressions on `const` objects.

Answer (score 1):

The `const` at the end means that the function will not change the object it is invoked on. This allows the function to be invoked on `const` objects.

Answer (score 1):

That second `const` is a qualifier for the object pointed by the implied argument `this`. It means the method is not allowed to modify its object. Indeed, comparison needn't - and shouldn't  - modify the object  being  compared.